# Car wont start and couldn't be jumped

Tags: honda, no-crank-no-start, pilot

Make: Honda / Model: Pilot / Year 2006 / Mileage: 166.4K

Was driving to an appointment and stopped at a red light. When it turned green, I pressed the accelerator and didnt move, then the car bucked and started moving and I started to hear a whining noise from the front right. About 100 feet later the battery light came on so I pulled into a parking lot. Parked, turned off the car and tried to start it again and no result. Grabbed the portable-jump kit from the trunk, full charge and tried to jump it; again, no result. When attempting to jump, there wasn't even a clicking noise as I have experienced in the past. Turning the key to position 1, none of the dashboard lights come on nor do any of the other electrical systems (radio, AC, etc...). Forgot to try and turn the headlights on to see if battery had power.

Getting it jumped (attempted) by a tow truck later before towing it to local shop.

Unsure of battery age but terminals were quite corroded. What else should I look for?

Comment: "terminals were quite corroded" There is your problem, replace the battery and have the battery cable terminals cleaned.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think we can get a good diagnosis based on this info unfortunately, just due to the number of things that could cause an issue like this.
So I'll start with the basics.

**Do you have fuel?** (check gas tank rather than relying on fuel gauge in-case its broken)

**Check the fuses box in the car, are there any broken fuses.**

Since you have no dash lights/accessories and start relay is not clicking, it indicates that even the starter motor relay isn't getting power let-alone the start motor. So my first thought is possibly one of your main fuses (sometimes called Fusable Links) has broken.
The whining could have been your alternator, which perhaps could have shorted out causing a main fuse to blow.

Your best bet is really to take it to a trusted mechanic, and get them to take a look.
Another option is to see if any local auto parts stores (I think AutoZone in US, SuperCheap Auto in NZ/AUS) have a battery tester you could borrow to test the battery and alternator. However you will likely need to go to a mechanic in the end.

Comment: Yes there is fuel. Didn't check fuse box. Dropping it off at the mechanic within the hour.